# Proof $\lim_{x \to -1^{-}}\log(1+\frac{1}{x})- \frac{1}{1+x}= +\infty$ without L'hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I want to prove that $$\lim_{x \to -1^{-}}\log(1+\frac{1}{x})- \frac{1}{1+x} = +\infty.$$
I know that (but I can't prove it also) $$\lim_{x\to -1^{-}}\log(1+\frac{1}{x})=-\infty.$$ and $$\lim_{x\to -1^{-}}\frac{-1}{1+x}=+\infty.$$ which means that I have an indeterminate form $-\infty+\infty$ but I don't know how to get over this IF.

Comment: If you find yourself in an $\infty-\infty$ case, combining them into a single fraction is always a good idea. See if you can apply some log rules once you do.

Comment: I tried this but I still have an IF : $ \frac{ \log((1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+1})-1}{x+1} $

Comment: Focus on $(1+1/x)^{x+1}$ Can you find this limit as $x\to-1^-$?

Comment: I don't see how can I find this limit. Can I write the $\log(1+\frac{1}{x})$ as $\log(\frac{x+1}{x})$ when $x\to -1^{-}$ ?

Comment: Try changing it to $e^{\ln((1+1/x)^{x+1})}$

Comment: when I do this I get "$ e^{0  (-\infty)}$" , an IF again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131166/discussion-between-bonnaduck-and-zchgarinch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$ u=-\frac1{x+1} $$
and then $x=-\frac{u+1}{u}$. So
$$ \log(1+\frac{1}{x})- \frac{1}{1+x} = u-\log(u+1) $$
and hence if $x\to-1^-$, then $u\to\infty$. For $u>6$,
$$ e^u=1+u+\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^3}{3!}+\cdots>1+u+\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^3}{3!}>u^2+2u+1=(u+1)^2. $$
So
$$ u-\log(u+1)>\log(u+1) $$
and hence
$$\lim_{x \to -1^{-}}\log(1+\frac{1}{x})- \frac{1}{1+x} = \lim_{u\to\infty}(u-\ln(u+1))=\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks but what if you take $u=1+\frac{1}{x}$ ? more easy no ?

Comment: It will be the same.

Comment: we dont need to use the 5 and sixth line no ?

Comment: We need them. Otherwise we can't obtain the result.

Comment: Let $y= 1+\frac{1}{x}$, then $x=\frac{1}{y-1}$, So :
$$\frac{1}{x+1}\left(\log(1+\frac{1}{x})(x+1)-1)\right)= (\frac{y-1}{y})\left(y \frac{\log(y)}{y-1}-1\right)$$. We have $\lim_{y\to 0^{+}} \frac{y-1}{y}=-\infty$ and $\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}y \frac{\log(y)}{y-1}=0$  so the global limit is equal to $+\infty$. Am I Right please?

Comment: I think it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you set $1+x=-u$, then $x=-u-1$ and
$$
1+\frac{1}{x}=1-\frac{1}{u+1}=\frac{u}{u+1}
$$
so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}\Bigl(\log u-\log(1+u)+\frac{1}{u}\Bigr)
=
\lim_{u\to0^+}\Bigl(\frac{u\log u+1}{u}-\log(1+u)\Bigr)
$$
and you can use
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}u\log u=0,\quad \lim_{u\to0}\log(1+u)=0
$$

Comment: Thanks for your idea.